# Плагин TableSorter.js в WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Пытаюсь использовать плагин TableSorter.js в WordPress.

```
wp_register_script('jquery.tablesorter', plugins_url( "js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js", __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.tablesorter' );
wp_register_script('jquery-latest', plugins_url( "js/jquery-latest.js", __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-latest' );
wp_register_script('script', plugins_url( "js/script.js", __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
```

Подключаю необходимые скрипты - по коду страницы вижу что они подключены, и ссылки на файлы скриптов работают правильно.

Но необходимые действия не выполняются.
В чем может быть причина? Могут ли подключаемые скрипты конфликтовать с существующими?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте порядок подключения скриптов. Подключение Jquery всегда должно идти самым первым.
Плюс оберните функцию вызова tablesorter в

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //вызов tablesorter
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter();
    }
); - так вызывается функция сортировки

Answer (score 0):

При регистрации своих скриптов надо использовать третий параметр функции `wp_register_script()` для указания зависимости скриптов. Это обеспечит их загрузку в правильном порядке. Порядок вызовов функции сам по себе роли не играет.

Попробуйте модифицировать свой код таким образом:

```
wp_register_script('jquery.tablesorter', plugins_url( "js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js", __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.tablesorter' );
wp_register_script('jquery-latest', plugins_url( "js/jquery-latest.js", __FILE__ ), array('jquery', 'jquery.tablesorter'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-latest' );
wp_register_script('script', plugins_url( "js/script.js", __FILE__ ), array('jquery', 'jquery.tablesorter', 'jquery.latest'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'script' );
```

В примере кода выше указывается, что:

`jquery.tablesorter` зависит от `jquery`

`jquery-latest` зависит  от `jquery` и `jquery.tablesorter`

`script` зависит  от `jquery`, `jquery.tablesorter` и `jquery-latest`.

Comment: К сожалению, тот же результат

Comment: Значит, надо больше кода. Какие "действия" не выполняются? Откуда они вызываются, что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Есть самописный плагин ВП, который выводит содержимое таблицы - работает. Нашел скрипты JQuery - TableSorter.js, которые позволяют осуществить сортировку таблицы без перезагрузки страницы. В "комплекте" три файла js и файл css. Их надо подключить и добавить название класса к моей таблице. После "подключения" скриптов - они появляются в коде страницы, но функция сортировки не выполняется. Если тот же набор использовать в "чистом" HTML-файле - работает